# SQLAlchemy not writing changes to database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been having a few issues with SQLAlchemy not writing changes, or rather the changes are lost when commit() is called.

I currently have a database of Cards, Decks (a collection of cards) and Users:

```
class Card(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # and a bunch of unrelated stuff

class Deck(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    cards = Column(PickleType)

class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    decks = relationship('Deck')
    active_deck_id = Column(Integer)
    deck = None
```

Note: Deck.cards is a dict() with the format *{Card.id : No. of cards}*

So when a User is loaded, the following happens:

```
def load_user(client, user):
    # bunch of unrelated stuff
    client.user = user
    if client.user.active_deck_id is not None:
        client.user.deck = db.session.query(db.Deck).get(client.user.active_deck_id)
```

And the function to add a Card to a Deck is as follows:

```
def add(args):
    # bunch of unrelated stuff
    card_name = ' '.join(args)
    s_card = db.session.query(db.Card).filter_by(name=card_name).first()
    if s_card is None:
        # errors & return
    if s_card.id in client.user.deck.cards:
        client.user.deck.cards[s_card.id] += 1
    else:
        client.user.deck.cards[s_card.id] = 1
    db.session.commit()
```

From what I can tell the add() function works correctly, however when the commit() is called the changes are lost.

I get the feeling that User.deck should be a relationship, however the problem with that is there is already User.decks.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach to User.deck that I don't know?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because SQLAlchemy doesn't know that your `cards` dict has changed, so it won't issue the update.

You'll want to set up a [`MutableDict`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html#sqlalchemy.ext.mutable.MutableDict) for it:

```
cards = Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(PickleType))
```

As for loading in `User.deck` manually, why would you do something that the ORM can do for you automatically? So what if you already have a `User.decks`? Why does that prevent you from have a `User.active_deck` or `User.deck` relationship?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!